# ALSA configuration with Linux Kernel for CS 4207

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, alsa, libalsa

So we have a custom hardware solution that has standard intel sound card, also found references to the CS4207 (link below). The system is old and we want to update the OS to Rocky 8 from Centos6.

[text](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4207_F4.pdf)

My assumption is that perhaps there was some custom changes done to the Linux kernel to make this device work? I can post the alsa-info.sh output if someone wants to see if, but as of right now SO considers it spam and wont post it!

For centos6, Node 0x06 is what I cant seem to get to replicate on rocky, the Cirrus ADC2. This appears to map to the pcmC0D2c, which is the capture device that does not show up in Rocky 8.

There are also other nodes 0x0c and 0x0d which have custom names. Are these custom changes done to the kernel?

```
Node 0x06 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x18051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="Cirrus Analog ADC2", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x33, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x3f 0x3f] [0x3f 0x3f]
  Converter: stream=3, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x1f5]: 8000 16000 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 8 samples
  Connection: 2
     0x0d* 0x0e

Node 0x0c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x41048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="CUSTOM11 Capture Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="CUSTOM10 Capture Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x028701a0: [Jack] Line In at Ext Front
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xa, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 1 samples
```

Again sorry for not posting all of the info, but SO considered the output spam. If anyone is intereted in helping just message on here and il post outputs at your request.

Attempted to compare sound modules, attempted to output alsa configs, attempted to understand documentation for CS4207.